# How to select from table-valued function via dynamic API?

Tags: jooq

I have requirements to be able to generate queries which select from table-valued functions rather than tables/views as the source.

Is this possible? The below doesn't seem to be valid jOOQ:

```
DSL.select(DSL.asterisk()).from(DSL.function(...))
```

And there doesn't seem to be anything like an `.asTable()` method I can call either on `function()` to cast it properly.

The docs mention that it's possible using the code generator but don't show an example using the dynamic API: [Table-valued functions](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/table-valued-functions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from using the internal API in [`TableImpl`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/TableImpl.html), which is used by generated code (look for constructors that take a `parameters` parameter, obviously, at your own risk, the API being internal!), there is no out of the box way to tell jOOQ that a table expression is, in fact, a function. I've created a feature request to add support for this in the future: [#14931](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14931)

But you can always use [plain SQL templates](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) already today:

```java
Table<?> t1 = DSL.table("function_name({0}, {1})", arg1, arg2);
Table<?> t2 = DSL.table("function_name({0})", DSL.list(arg1, arg2));
```

That plain SQL template doesn't know it's a function, nor does it know its row type, but for your purposes, it might be good enough?